# Intentionally reduce speed of ddrescue

Tags: linux, ddrescue

(first time poster) I want to slow down how fast ddrescue copies data. I'm imaging a hard drive from my linux laptop to my windows desktop. ddrescue is able to run faster than my computer can download what it gives, so its choking out my computer's internet. I image things like this occasionally, and want to know if there's a way to choke ddrescue down a little, either from the Windows desktop, or the linux laptop. (Windows 10, Parted Magic)

Thanks for your help?

Comment: probably answer to this [How to Throttle per process I/O to a max limit?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48152/64187) is what you may use.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution for ddrescue seems to be a --max-read-rate=[bytes] argument, at least in my case. Just copied my failing usb drive with 10 MB/s limit without any errors, saved my week.